# Get prev directory path in a variable in linux

Tags: sh

I am trying to get the parent directory of a given directory in a variable in linux script but I am unable to get it.

```
MN_CURR=/home/sshekhar/Desktop
MN_PREV=`$MN_CURR/..`
echo " Displayng $MN_PREV"
```

I am using CentOS. Can anyone please help?

Comment: `MN_PREV=${MN_CURR%/*}` See [POSIX Programmers Guide - 2.6.2 Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)

Comment: It worked. Thanks @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Glad to help, save the link to the POSIX Guide if you are doing a lot of shell scripting. Note that `sh` is very limited compared to bash or ksh or zsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from my comment, when using POSIX shell, while the parameter expansions are limited compared to a more advanced shell such as bash, ksh, or zsh, POSIX shell does provide expansions to handle string length and substring removal.

In your case you want to remove the last component of the path (the suffix beginning with `'/'`) leaving the parent directory. For that you can use:

```
MN_PREV=${MN_CURR%/*}
```

(which will remove all characters from the right -- up to and including the last `'/'`)

The reference documentation for the POSIX shell parameter expansions can be found at [POSIX Programmers Guide - 2.6.2 Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02). The expansions concerning string length and substring removal are:

```
${#parameter}
```

**String Length.** The length in characters of the value of parameter shall be substituted. If parameter is `'*' or '@'`, the result of the expansion is unspecified. If parameter is unset and set -u is in effect, the expansion shall fail.

```
${parameter%[word]}
```

**Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern.** The word shall be expanded to produce a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with the smallest portion of the suffix matched by the pattern deleted. If present, word shall not begin with an unquoted '%'.

```
${parameter%%[word]}
```

**Remove Largest Suffix Pattern.** The word shall be expanded to produce a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with the largest portion of the suffix matched by the pattern deleted.

${parameter#[word]}

**Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern.** The word shall be expanded to produce a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with the smallest portion of the prefix matched by the pattern deleted. If present, word shall not begin with an unquoted '#'.

```
${parameter##[word]}
```

**Remove Largest Prefix Pattern.** The word shall be expanded to produce a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with the largest portion of the prefix matched by the pattern deleted.